# How to display the First Name and Last Name in the Lable by the ID of the profile you are logged into?

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I am creating a WPF application with a MySQL database, I wrote the following code so that the username would be displayed in the Lable, but for some reason it gives me only the last user in my database. How can I make it so that I would log into the account and see information only on it? Those. I go under user 1 and I will see user 1 in the field, and for example not user 101

```
                "server=; username=; password=; database=u1831430_excurtion";
            MySqlConnection connectionString = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            MySqlCommand command = connectionString.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = $"SELECT `FirstName` FROM `Login` WHERE 1";
            command.CommandText = $"SELECT `LastName` FROM `Login` WHERE 1";
            //command.CommandText = $"SELECT `ID` FROM `Login` WHERE 1";
            MySqlDataReader myReader;

            try
            {
                connectionString.Open();
                myReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    //ID_Label.Content = myReader[0].ToString();
                    FN_Label.Content = myReader[0].ToString();
                    LN_Label.Content = myReader[0].ToString();
                }
            }
```

I tried to add a field with an ID, but after I did that, all my Labels began to fill in with the last ID from the table

To make it possible to display the last name and first name, you need:

Create a class where variables will be stored:
user ID
Username

```
public class global
    {
        public static int userid;
        public static string username;
    }
```

Next, when checking strings for fullness, you need to declare variables and translate them into a string

```
 DB db = new DB();
                string userName = TB_Name.Text;
                string userPass = PB_Password.Password;

                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Login = @uL AND Password = @uP AND Role = 2" , db.GetConnection());

                command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userPass;

                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(table);
                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    global.userid = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString());
                    global.username = table.Rows[0]["Login"].ToString();
                   UserPanel();
                }
```

After that, in the user line, you need to assign the value of the user ID to your label with the ID

```
 string query = $"SELECT FirstName, LastName, ID, img FROM Login WHERE ID = {ID_Label.Content = global.userid}";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, db.GetConnection());
            db.openConnection();
            MySqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    FN_Label.Content = myReader.GetString("FirstName");
                    LN_Label.Content = myReader.GetString("LastName");
                }
            }
```

Comment: You are getting all records returned because your where clause will be true for all records. You need to compare username.

Comment: Andy how it do it ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-parameters.html

Comment: I still can't figure out how to refer to the Username because the textbox is on a different page

Comment: Aren't you checking the password and username when they log in?  Seems like this logic should be there and the user's name etc stashed in the dependency injection container or a property on app or something kind of global.

Comment: Andy I was able to make this function, thanks for the help. Now my question has a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it possible to display the last name and first name, you need:

Create a class where variables will be stored:
user ID
Username

```
public class global
    {
        public static int userid;
        public static string username;
    }
```

Next, when checking strings for fullness, you need to declare variables and translate them into a string

```
 DB db = new DB();
                string userName = TB_Name.Text;
                string userPass = PB_Password.Password;

                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

                MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Login WHERE Login = @uL AND Password = @uP AND Role = 2" , db.GetConnection());

                command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userName;
                command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = userPass;

                adapter.SelectCommand = command;
                adapter.Fill(table);
                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    global.userid = Convert.ToInt32(table.Rows[0]["ID"].ToString());
                    global.username = table.Rows[0]["Login"].ToString();
                   UserPanel();
                }
```

After that, in the user line, you need to assign the value of the user ID to your label with the ID

```
 string query = $"SELECT FirstName, LastName, ID, img FROM Login WHERE ID = {ID_Label.Content = global.userid}";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, db.GetConnection());
            db.openConnection();
            MySqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            try
            {
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    FN_Label.Content = myReader.GetString("FirstName");
                    LN_Label.Content = myReader.GetString("LastName");
                }
            }
```